# Getting Error, Unable to set the formulaArray property of the range class

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Please help,
I am getting this error whenever I am trying to run macro for array formula.

Below is the macro code:

```
Sub MacroNew ()

Range ("B16").FormulaArray = "= IF (Rows (Template!C$16:C16)> $F$8, """, INDEX (THICK! $A$3:A$1000, SMALL (IF (THICK! $A$3: $A$1000>=Template! $C$7, IF (THICK! $A$3: $A$1000<=Template! $C$8, IF (THICK! $A$3: $A$1000>=Template! $C$9, IF (THICK! $A$3: $A$1000<=Template! $C$10, ROW (THICK!$A$3: $A$1000) - ROW (THICK!$A$3)+1)))), ROWS (Template!C$16:C16)))"

Selection.Autofill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range ("A1:A85).select 

End Sub ()
```

Comment: Change `End Sub ()` with `End Sub`

Comment: Also Add the Formula that you have applied in the Cell of your worksheet.

Comment: Delete all of those extra spaces eg `THICK! $A$3: $A$1000`

Comment: Thank you Mikku and Tim, I will let both you know the feedback on this on Monday when I will be in office

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using it in VBA, you have to use `""""` instead of `""` to insert a Formula in the cell.

**Change the Code to:**

```
Sub MacroNew()

Range("B16").FormulaArray = "=IF(Rows(Template!C$16:C16)> $F$8, """", INDEX(THICK!$A$3:A$1000, SMALL(IF(THICK!$A$3: $A$1000>=Template!$C$7, IF(THICK!$A$3:$A$1000<=Template!$C$8, IF(THICK!$A$3:$A$1000>=Template!$C$9, IF(THICK!$A$3:$A$1000<=Template!$C$10, ROW(THICK!$A$3:$A$1000) - ROW(THICK!$A$3)+1)))), ROWS(Template!C$16:C16)))"

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A85")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Mikku, Just want to know how do I break this array formula.

Comment: Post a New question for it. One Problem per question :)

Comment: Ok, I have posted new question on this.  Please help on that. Thank you